# AngularJS Cannot pull data from a Json file

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am trying to use AngularJS to pull data from a json file and plug that data into a table row.

```js
var Products = angular.module('Products', []);
Products.controller('ProductsController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("/Products.json")
    .success(function(productsdata) {
      $scope.Products = productsdata.DATA;
      console.log($scope.Products);
    })
    .error(function(error) {
      $scope.error = error;
      console.log($scope.Products);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="Products" ng-controller="ProductsController">
  <div>
    <table class="table" ng-hide="{{error}}">
      <tr>
        <th>id:</th>
        <th>name:</th>
        <th>description:</th>
        <th>category:</th>
        <th>price:</th>
        <th>image:</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in Products">
        <td>{{Products.IDPRODUCTS[$index]}}</td>
        <td>{{Products.NAME[$index]}}</td>
        <td>{{Products.DESCRIPTION[$index]}}</td>
        <td>{{Products.CATEGORY[$index]}}</td>
        <td>{{Products.PRICE[$index] | currency}}</td>
        <td>{{Products.IMG[$index]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div ng-show="{{error}}">
      There was an error
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm currently not receiving any errors from my chrome debugging and the error function that i programmed into the script is not firing.

```
.error(function (error) {
$scope.error = error;
console.log($scope.Products);});
```

Please, any help on why it's not working as expected would be great.

Here is my little project.

http://embed.plnkr.co/W2ALqBu16czJBlzfCfXj/preview

Comment: ng-controller needs to be on a parent element, not the element with ng-repeat.

Comment: The code to reproduce the problem you're seeing should be reproduced in the question itself; if you have any links to an external site, they should be supplemental, and not required for us to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks George, I'll change it.

Comment: Try this ... needs some work, but functional version of your code. http://plnkr.co/edit/sQ0uT38FHtZpHyrKj329?p=preview

Comment: Thanks rfornal 4, could you explain the problems you saw with my code?

Comment: Firstly, you need to move ng-controller as your controller is never called as it stands. Move it to a parent element e.g. like so: `<table ng-controller="ProductsController" class="table" ng-hide="{{error}}">`

Comment: Also the reference to your json file doesn't work in the plunker. Use `./Products.json` (add a dot in front of the slash to use the current directory)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That's got it working on plunker. Now to get it working in my actually development server.